# Get a list of names and ARNs of instances using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'd like to get a simple list of all instances in a certain region, each record should include id, ARN and name of an instance.
I've tried using

```
ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1
```

but can't find an ARN in the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could construct the ARN if it's possible in your use case by knowing the region, account id + the instance ID:

```
arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/instance-id
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-1234567890abcdef0
```

And actually -- as I look at the JSON response, `OwnerId` appears to contain the `account-id` so constructing this from the result of `describe-instances` should be fairly simple.

**EDIT:** An example using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to construct the output you're looking for:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.Reservations[] | .OwnerId as $OwnerId | ( .Instances[] | { "ARN": "arn:aws:ec2:\(.Placement.AvailabilityZone[:-1]):\($OwnerId):instance/\(.InstanceId)", "AvailabilityZone": "\(.Placement.AvailabilityZone)", InstanceId, PublicDnsName, PrivateDnsName, Tags} )' | jq -s .
```

which would produce output like:

```
[
  {
    "ARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-0a9842b2da1xxxxxx",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
    "InstanceId": "i-0a9842b2da1xxxxxx",
    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-72-32-69-225.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-68.ec2.internal",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Value": "my-beanstalk",
        "Key": "elasticbeanstalk:environment-name"
      },
      {
        "Value": "awseb-e-emiwxxxxxx-stack",
        "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-0a9842b2ca1xxxxxx",
    "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
    "InstanceId": "i-0a9842b2ca1xxxxxx",
    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-72-32-69-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-69.ec2.internal",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "Value": "my-beanstalk-2",
        "Key": "elasticbeanstalk:environment-name"
      },
      {
        "Value": "awseb-e-emizxxxxxx-stack",
        "Key": "aws:cloudformation:stack-name"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @dimid: updated to show how it could be constructed with jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way not to repeat the region? BTW, I'd also add the tags 

`aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.Reservations[] | .OwnerId as $OwnerId | ( .Instances[] | { "ARN": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:\($OwnerId):instance/\(.InstanceId)", "AvailabilityZone": "\(.Placement.AvailabilityZone)", InstanceId, PublicDnsName, PrivateDnsName, Tags } )`

Comment: If every AZ only uses a single letter then we might be able to substring the last character off of AvailabilityZone. Will take a look at the JQ docs and see if this is possible.

Comment: updated to use substring -1 @dimid -- now you don't have to repeat the region.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example — previously from my entry in SO Docs.

---

Instances have a lot of metadata that gets returned from a call to `describe-instances`, but often times you just want to see the basics. You can use a JMESPath query combined with table output to show concise instance information in an easily readable way.

`aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key == 'Name'].Value | [0], Id: InstanceId, State: State.Name, Type: InstanceType}"`

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|                 DescribeInstances                 |
+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
|    Id     |     Name      |  State   |   Type     |
+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
|  i-abc123 |  None         |  stopped |  m3.large  |
|  i-def456 |  amazon linux |  stopped |  t2.micro  |
|  i-ghi789 |  proxy        |  running |  t2.micro  |
+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
```

Now lets break that up piece by piece. First, we have `--output table`. This produces a colorized table representation of the response. This is generally most useful with commands that return small sets of data or where you have filtered the data down.

Now onto the `--query`. This one looks long, but it is actually quite simple. The first part is `Reservations[].Instances[]`. This returns a flattened list of all the returned instances.

The next part of the query is encapsulated with `.{}`. What this is doing is creating a new json object for each item in the list where each value is a JMESPath query to be applied to the source object (in this case, an Instance). Most of these are very simple, but `Name` is a bit more complex.

The full query to get `Name` is `Tags[?Key == 'Name'].Value | [0]`. The first part of that, `Tags[?Key == 'Name']` is searching the instance's tags for a tag whose key is `Name`. The second half `.Value | [0]` is selecting the values of each of those tags and then taking the first item from the list (in this case, there will only ever be one).

Exactly what you want in that table is completely up to you. If you wanted to add DNS information, for instance, you could easily add a new key `DNS: PublicDnsName`:

`aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{Name: Tags[?Key == 'Name'].Value | [0], Id: InstanceId, State: State.Name, Type: InstanceType, DNS: PublicDnsName}"`

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                           DescribeInstances                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
|                        DNS                       |    Id     |     Name      |  State   |   Type     |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
|                                                  |  i-abc123 |  None         |  stopped |  m3.large  |
|                                                  |  i-def456 |  amazon linux |  stopped |  t2.micro  |
|  ec2-192-168-1-1.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com |  i-ghi789 |  proxy        |  running |  t2.micro  |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+----------+------------+
```

---

It is easy enough to change to suit the specific details you want and doesn't require that you install additional tools.

Comment: +1. I looked at using `--query` criteria but didn't see any way that outputting the ARN could be accomplished solely from the response without piping to `jq` as it seemed to need variable support. An example of how this can be done with `--query` criteria would be a great add to this answer.